# Flutter - Basics for building a game

Tags: flutter, dart

I am thinking of making a DOt and box game using flutter...Any help any blog to refer that how should I start?

2 players ( a player that completes the fourth side of a square box, color box and play again)

When all boxes colored -> game ends.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few tutorials around this.

Have a look at the following

1. [2d engine](https://www.spritewidget.com/)
2. [Games already made](https://flutterawesome.com/tag/games/)
3. [Multiplatformer game with tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/from-zero-to-a-multiplatform-flutter-game-in-a-week-8245da931c7e)
4. [2d game with tutorial](https://blog.geekyants.com/building-a-2d-game-in-flutter-a-comprehensive-guide-913f647846bc?gi=ab17b5f68298)
5. [Tick Tac To](https://medium.com/@dmilicic/building-a-tic-tac-toe-app-in-flutter-e893792f1fed)

There are alot of usefull tutorials, you can just google abit.

Comment: Can you please provide some blogs on the same game using different languages made by people?